# PosgresSQL Trigger

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

When a new row is inserted into table `forumtopics` (cols: id | userid), than I want to do a trigger that makes an insert into table `upvotes`, that uses the id and userid from the forumtopics row.

So the upvotes table would look: id | userid | forumtopicsid (id from original insert)

How may I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create a trigger function, e.g. (assuming that `upvotes.id` is of type `serial`):

```
create or replace function before_insert_on_forumtopics()
returns trigger language plpgsql as $$
begin
    insert into upvotes (userid, forumtopicsid)
    values (new.userid, new.id);
    return new;
end $$;
```

Next, create a trigger:

```
create trigger before_insert_on_forumtopics
before insert on forumtopics
for each row 
execute procedure before_insert_on_forumtopics();
```

Read in the documentation about [Trigger Behavior](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/trigger-definition.html), [Trigger Procedures](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-trigger.html) and [CREATE TRIGGER](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-createtrigger.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TRIGGER init_upvote
    AFTER INSERT ON forumtopics
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE function_that_inserts_into_upvote(NEW.id, NEW.userid);
```